# How to get aria-labelledby value

Tags: javascript, html

My question is how can I get the value from aria-labelledby value?
I have two method let user input, one is text another is drop-down list，
but I can't find how to select value from same label.
Here is my code

```
    <label id="lblconnect">Connect:</label>
    <input id="connect text" name="connect text" aria-label="lblconnect">
    <select id="connect" name="connect" aria-label="lblconnect">
        <option hidden selected>Choose Connect Type</option>
        <option value="wired">Wired</option>
        <option value="wifi">WIFI</option>
        <option value="bt">BT</option>
        <option value="ble">BLE</option>
        <option value="ble5">BLE5</option>
        <option value="lora">LoRa</option>
        <option value="nb-iot">NB-IoT</option>
        <option value="zigbee">ZIgBee</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to do? are you asking about the html attribute or doing something in javascript?

Comment: I have two method let user fill in the form, one is text another is drop-down list, but I don't want to check it two times. I create function in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to get the value of the Select Field. If so, you can get it by using its Id

```
const x = document.getElementById("connect");
console.log(x.value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I want to autocheck my value is from text or drop-down list.